# Sumar los 2 primeros numeros de 1 campo (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy efectuando un Query en donde debo sacar los 2 primeros numeros de 1 campo y luego sumarlos.

ejemplo:

**Tengo la siguiente tabla**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Luego tengo el siguiente Query**

```
SELECT [id],[nif],[nombre],[apellido1],[apellido2]
FROM [universidad].[dbo].[persona] ORDER BY nif ASC
(SELECT substring (nif,1,2) as ok 
FROM [universidad].[dbo].[persona]) ORDER BY nif ASC
```

**como resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si bien saco los 2 primeros numeros, no llego a como volver a separarlos o bien guardarlos en alguna variable para luego volver a efectuar un substring supongo y despues sumarlos, no se si existe alguna otra forma mas facil y yo me estoy enredando hace poco que estoy en SQL quizas mi Query sea medio desordenado :(

Comment: O sea que quieres la suma del primer caracter y el segundo caracter de la columna nif?

Comment: @LuisCazares correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT substring (nif,1,2) as ok, substring (nif,1,1) + substring (nif,2,1) as suma
FROM [universidad].[dbo].[persona]) ORDER BY nif ASC
```

Donde la siguiente setencia se separan el primer numero y se le suma la extracción del segundo numero:

```
substring (nif,1,1) + substring (nif,2,1) as suma
```

El resultado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Realize lo que indicaste pero al final me une los substring en ves de sumarlos :( , ahora estoy googleando para ver si hay alguna alternativa de guardarlos en variable esos Substring o algo similar, si llego con la respuesta lo indicare, gracias de todos modos, seguire buscando alternativas :(

Comment: @SergioLeon es que lo intente en Oracle y me funciono pero ya al pasarlo a sqlserver funciona de manera diferente :|

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo mencionaron antes, necesitas separar cada caracter por separado usando `SUBSTRING()`, pero además necesitas convertirlo en un valor numérico. Para eso, puedes usar las distintas opciones para convertir como `CAST()`, `CONVERT()`, `TRY_CAST()`, `TRY_CONVERT()`, `TRY_PARSE()`. Cada función tiene una razón específica para su uso, por lo que debes seleccionar la que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades.

```
SELECT  [id],
        [nif],
        [nombre],
        [apellido1],
        [apellido2],
        TRY_CONVERT( int, substring (nif,1,1)) + TRY_CONVERT( int, substring (nif,2,1)) as suma
FROM [universidad].[dbo].[persona] p
ORDER BY nif ASC;
```